# Using edgeNGram filter in Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I am trying to use EdgeNGramFilterFactory to index a name field. I tried mimicking the schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text_prefix" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ISOLatin1AccentFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="20"  side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ISOLatin1AccentFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

...

<field name="text_prefix" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
```

and in my model I have:

```
searchable do
  text :name, :as => :text_prefix
```

However it seems to have no effect. I am missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by having no effect ? What are you checking for ?? what are you querying for ??

Comment: I want to search for "Ne" and get entries like "New York". Currently it returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your schema looks good except for one thing: your `text_prefix` field is of type `string` and not `text_prefix`, thus it doesn't use `EdgeNGramFilterFactory`.

You should change this line

```
<field name="text_prefix" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
```

like this

```
<field name="text_prefix" stored="false" type="text_prefix" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks it works correctly. However do you know why the build-in `<field name="text"` type="string"` seems to match got  field_type:text instead of field_type:string? (like all the filter that is configured in `text` works)?

Comment: @lulalala Glad to know it works. Sorry I don't get your question, can you rephrase it? Usually the string fieldType is not tokenized etc. it's just a simple string.

Comment: don't worry I got it now. Sunspot's says its default field type is "text" but it is actually a **dynamic** "text" field, not the static "text" type that is actually a string.